# How to set minimum & maximum y value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, touch

I am implementing a draggable UIView in my application. The codes I have worked fine but I would like to set a restricted area the UIView can be moved.

My codes:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if( [touch view] == camview)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view;
        startX = camview.center.x;
        startY= location.y - camview.center.y;        
    }
}


- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if( [touch view] == camview)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        location.y =location.y - startY;
        location.x = startX;
        camview.center = location;
    }
}
```

So how can I set the minimum and maximum y value that the UIView can be dragged?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in making sure the view frame doesn't go over or under a certain y value you could do the following,

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    CGFloat minY, maxY; //The position in your self.view you are interested in

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if( [touch view] == camview)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        location.y = location.y - startY;
        location.y = MIN(location.y,maxY);   //Always <= maxY
        location.y = MAX(location.y,minY);   //Always >= minY
        location.x = startX;
        camview.center = location;
    }
}
```